# Run collection in Insomnia

Tags: rest, testing, postman-collection-runner, insomnia

I'm looking for a way to run requests sequentially within my Insomnia collection, similar to how it's done using the collection runner in Postman. My collection contains a series of requests, and I'd like to execute them in a specific order to thoroughly test the functionality of my API.

Is there a feature or approach in Insomnia that allows me to achieve this sequential execution of requests in a collection? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

[Different request in my Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVwgt.png)

I was researching it, but it is not as straightforward as Postman. I think you have to install plugins or use an external app

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've found your answer yet, but just in case:
What we've had to do at my company is to create a document, create or import the collection in the document.
Then you tap into the "Test" tab and create a test suite. From there, you would need to create tests, one each for each request you want to run. One request per test is allowed, so there's, unfortunately, no way to just set a collection run off the way it can be done in Postman. At least, not that I've found.